# Can't install Python virtual environment for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I'm following [these instructions](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/#install3-osx) on installing Python 3 with with Homebrew on my MacBook running Mac OSX High Sierra.

I'm having trouble with this step:

> *Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your ~/.profile file*
>
> *`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`*

After updating `~/.profile` and running `python --version`, I still see `Python 2.7.10`.

This seems to be an issue because when I follow the [next page](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvironments-ref) to install a virtual environment using `pip install --user pipenv`, I get the following warning after installation completes:

> The scripts pewtwo, pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/charliesneath/Library/**Python/2.7**/bin' which is not on PATH.

It seems like my system is not properly prioritizing Homebrew's installation of Python 3.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you calling the virtualenv command? `virtualenv -p <path to python3>`?

Comment: What is the output you receive after you do `brew install python` according to the instructions of your link?

Comment: `python3 -m venv env && source env/bin/active` ?

Comment: @MikeTung Add the command I used to install the virtualenv—is that helpful?

Comment: @MikeTung I'm getting `-bash: virtualenv: command not found` when running that command + path. 

I'm also getting `-bash: pipenv: command not found` after trying to install pipenv with `pip install --user pipenv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this once I eventually understood the [following instructions](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#installing-pipenv):

> *If `pipenv` isn’t available in your shell after installation, you’ll need to add the user base‘s binary directory to your `PATH`.*
>
> *On Linux and macOS you can find the user base binary directory by running `python -m site --user-base` and adding `bin` to the end. For example, this will typically print `~/.local` (with `~` expanded to the absolute path to your home directory) so you’ll need to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH`. You can set your `PATH` permanently by modifying `~/.profile`.*

My system outputs `/Users/charliesneath/Library/Python/3.6` when running the command, so I added the following to `~/.profile`:

`export PATH="~/Library/Python/3.6/bin"`

**Does anyone know why my system is not outputting `~/.local` as suggested by the instructions above?**

---

EDIT: It seems like version of Python I've installed is considered "framework build," and according to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE), the path I added to `~/.profile` is the default "user base directory" for this framework:

> **site.USER_BASE**: Default value is ~/.local for UNIX and Mac OS X non-framework builds, ~/Library/Python/X.Y for Mac framework builds, and %APPDATA%\Python for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac, when you install python3, it is installed in a different path as those examples you are citing. To find out where the python3 is installed, type the command line:

```
which python3
```

It will return `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3`.

Add the following lines to .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Comment: Do you know why this needs to be added to `.bash_profile` and not `.profile`?

Comment: Environment variables are usually put into `.bash_profile` because that is where the first interactive login shell(e.g. ssh login) will look for, all the default environment settings are put in `.bash_profile`. They are set only once but inherited in all child shells. If `.bash_profile` is not found in the home directory, Bash will then search for `.bash_login` and `.profile`. `.profile` can hold the same configurations as .bash_profile or .bash_login. It generally contain individual profile settings that override the variables set in the `/etc/profile` file.